Why doesn't pycharm show tensor's dimension information now
enter image description here
Why doesn't pycharm show tensor's dimension information now.Pycharm used to show dimensions, now why not。Pycharm used to show dimensions, now why not。 Pycharm used to show dimensions, now why notPycharm used to show dimensions, now why notPycharm used to show dimensions, now why not

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
